# i'm trying to make my music player to play automatically

Tags: html, html5-audio, audio-player

This is a normal music player's HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="zui you ji.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I make it play songs automatically?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=autoplay+html5+audio&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=QlmcUvyBMcGWhQenoYCoCg

Comment: add `autoplay = "autoplay"` attribute to `audio` tag

Comment: how about adding a list of song to the same player?
is that possible?

Comment: You would most likely need multiple buttons, that when clicked changes the `<audio>` src parameter.

Comment: how about adding a playlist under the player?
how can i make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this html5 code.....

```
 <html>
<body>

<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="zui you ji.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `autoplay` attribute to your HTML 5 audio tag.

```
<html>
    <body>

    <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls>
      <source src="zui you ji.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `autoplay="autoplay"` just `autoplay` as it is